# Showing JFrame in a non Raster Graphics Configuration

Tags: java, swing, off-screen

Greetings,

I'm trying to get a JFrame drawing in a non screen device. The JFrame constructor has a

```
 JFrame(GraphicsConfiguration)
```

to seemingly allow this:

My First attempt was to create my own GraphicsConfiguration, who's GraphicsDevice reported GraphicsDevice.TYPE_IMAGE_BUFFER when getType() was called.

However JFrame.init specifically looks for the type and throws an exception if the type isn't TYPE_RASTER_SCREEN:

```
    if (graphicsConfig.getDevice().getType() !=
        GraphicsDevice.TYPE_RASTER_SCREEN) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("not a screen device");
    }
```

Next i tried to make the GraphicsDevice i returned report GraphicsDevice.TYPE_RASTER_SCREEN. This allowed the JFrame to be initialized correctly, but when it went to display it, I got

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: TestGraphicsConfiguration cannot be cast to sun.awt.X11GraphicsConfig
```

So i've run out of ideas, on how to draw a JFrame that doesn't show up on the screen, but is never the less fully layed out and functional.

Am going down a rabbit hole here, or can this be done?

Comment: Maybe this is another way to achieve your goal.  What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: just playing around. was looking at testing swing code, and saw how most tools that do it, do it, and didn't particularly like it. I didn't have anything real concrete in mind, just exploring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Java [top-level container](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) such as [`JFrame`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) requires access to a [peer component](http://www.particle.kth.se/~lindsey/JavaCourse/Book/Part1/Java/Chapter06/AWT.html) native to the host platform, typically via JNI. Alternatively, you may be able to use a [`BufferedImage`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) or `java.awt.headless` mode, as discussed [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/headless/).

Addendum:

> I wonder if "any human" can replace how peers are selected.

I don't know how to *replace* a particular peer component, but it's possible to evoke platform-specific native components; [Java Native Access (JNA)](http://jna.java.net/) is one such avenue. As an extreme example, this [6502 JVM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vm02/) runs in 128K on an 8-bit processor running at 1 MHz. The demos, including [source](http://home.roadrunner.com/~jbmatthews/apple2.html#rp1j) for the lower right screenshot, were compiled using `javac`.

Comment: Sorry this is a bit sketchy, but it might offer a foundation for clarification.

Comment: i suppose you can't print JFrames either then, i wonder if 'any human' can replace how peers are selected. Odd that the peer selection algorithm isn't tied to the GraphicsConfiguration.